# Categorical histogram labels

Tags: matlab, histogram, matlab-figure, categorical-data

I've created a categorical histogram :

```
h = histogram( categorical( emotions{startIndex:endIndex,:} ) )

h.Categories
ans =
  1×5 cell array
    {'ANGER'}    {'CONTEMPT'}    {'DISGUST'}    {'JOY'}    {'SADNESS'}

>> h.Values
ans =
   164    26    18   191     1
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to display labels (i.e.`h.Values`) on the histogram bars.
Following [*this post*](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91709-how-do-i-label-the-bars-in-my-histogram), I tried this:

```
text(h.Values, h.Categories, num2str(h.Values'), 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Bottom' );
```

but I just get:

> Error using text First two or three arguments must be numeric doubles.

but the problem is my `x` values are never going to be numeric, they're categorical.  How to fix it?

---

For a reproducible example, this would do:

```
emotions = { 'JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','ANGER','ANGER','CONTEMPT','CONTEMPT','CONTEMPT','JOY','ANGER','ANGER','ANGER','ANGER'}
emotions = emotions.';
t = cell2table(emotions)
histogram(categorical(emotions))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have interchanged the first two input arguments of `text` and `h.Categories` is not numeric double which it needs to be (as the error message is suggesting you).
So the solution is:

```
emotions = {'JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY','JOY', ...
     'JOY','ANGER','ANGER','CONTEMPT','CONTEMPT','CONTEMPT','JOY', ...
     'ANGER','ANGER','ANGER','ANGER'};
% emotions = emotions.';    %No need of this line
% t = cell2table(emotions); %No need of this line
h = histogram(categorical(emotions));

text(1:numel(h.Values), h.Values, num2str(h.Values.'), ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Bottom');
```

***Result:***

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to check this out Sardar, it solves my problem.